# Is the obfuscation of Pyarmor always random?

Tags: python, build, obfuscation, distribute, pyarmor

I would like to know if the obfuscation of Pyarmor is always random each time I generate a new obfuscated build with the "pack" command, or if I have to change some variable in the command line to change the "seed". I need to generate different builds for each user that I will distribute my product, can someone help me with an idea of how to do this automatically?